# Magento 2.1 product page change wishlist button to font icon

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist, fonts

Magento 2.1 
product page 
I need to change the wishlist button to font icon "heart" which is the default in the luma theme, but when I apply my theme it shows a button...
Does anyone knows how to change this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the piece of code that turns this to an icon:

```
.product-social-links,
    .block-bundle-summary,
    .product-item,
    .table-comparison {
        .action.towishlist {
            &:extend(.abs-actions-addto all);
            .lib-icon-font-symbol(
            @_icon-font-content: @icon-wishlist-full,
            @_icon-font-position: before
            );
        }
    }
```